# Condiciones en las tablas Pivot Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

estoy tratando de realizar una condición en la tabla secundaria en una relación de muchos a muchos en laravel.

Modelo principal: `Tipo_Habitacion`,

Modelo secundario: `Lang`,

Pivot: tabla `th_langs` la unión de los dos modelos.

Así esta la BD, para entender mejor
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos de la tabla `langs`
[image: Son los datos de la tabla langs por ahora dos idiomas]

*No se como condicionar por el `codigo` de la tabla `langs`

así esta mi función:

```
class Tipo_Habitacion extends Model

{
protected $table='tipo_habitaciones';
public function idiomas()
{
    if (Session::has("lang")) { // si hay session la captura
        $idioma = Session::get("lang");
    } else {
        $idioma = substr($request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2); // analiza el idioma del navegador
        if ($idioma != 'es' && $idioma != 'en') {
            $idioma = 'en'; // si es diferente por defecto codigo es 'en'
        }
    }
    return $this->belongsToMany(Langs::class, 'th_langs', 'tipo_habitaciones_id', 'langs_id')
    ->withPivot('id','titulo','descripcion','descripcion2'));
}

}
```

como puedo poner la condicion en `belongsToMany`
para la tabla SECUNDARIA,

solo encontré  `->wherePivot('campo_tabla', valor_campo);` pero eso para es para la tabla pivot.

PD: la variable session `$idioma` irá igualada al `codigo` [`'codigo', $idioma`].

DETALLER:
-Estoy filtrando por `codigo` por que es una pagina multiidiomas. 
-En laravel hay un middleware que detecta que dioma escogio el usuario mediante la web escoge un idioma o no. 
[image: idiomas a escoger]

Como se muestra el codigo es de rojo, laravel lo captura y el middleware hace su trabajo.

entonces yo uso la variable session `if (Session::has("lang")) { }else{}` si existe o no segun eso capturo el `codigo` y trabajo en la BD.

Comment: ¿Qué significa «condicionar por el código»? ¿Podrías mostrarnos cómo sería el resultado esperado? No me queda muy claro.

Comment: Claro voy a editar la pregunta, añadiendo más detalles.

Answer (score 1):

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Langs::class, 'th_langs', 'tipo_habitaciones_id', 'langs_id')
    ->withPivot('id','titulo','descripcion','descripcion2'))
    ->where('langs.codigo', $idioma);
```

Si te da error, el detalle del error te señala el query que está usando, sería cuestion ajustarlo, las relaciones lo que hacen es ejecutar un query por cada registro si se solicita.